# Deploy from GitHub Key problem Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, deployment, capistrano, ssh-keys

I have a Rails app that I deploy using Capistrano with `cap production deploy`

This works fine but if I reboot my machine I get the following error:

> 01 git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
> 01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> 01
> 01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> 01 and the repository exists.

To resolve this I need to run the following two commands:

```
ssh-add
```

and

```
ssh -A deploy@{{IP here}} 'git ls-remote git@github.com:{{repo URL here}}'
```

This allows me to deploy.

There's obviously something wrong here where it's not storing the key details.

Can someone please help me to understand what that second command actually does and why I have to re-run them after a reboot?

Answer (score 0):

The second command “forwards” your private key from your local machine to the remote machine (with -A). That temporarily places your private key on the remote server. That private key is then used by the remote machine to authenticate against GitHub.

The first command sets up which private key to forward to remote servers.

See https://dev.to/levivm/how-to-use-ssh-and-ssh-agent-forwarding-more-secure-ssh-2c32 for more on how to use ssh key forwarding.

If your remote server IP address is always the same you can configure ssh to always forward the key to that IP and you won’t need the -A part of the command.

It might be useful for you to wrap the commands in a bash script which you can run and it’ll do both commands for you.

### security warning

Your “private” ssh key should never be shared. The ssh key forwarding (which you’re doing now) temporarily and briefly puts your private key on your remote server - which is probably a secure enough approach. But, do not be tempted to copy it up to the remote server permanently.